# Oracle SQL IF ELSE CALCULATION GIVE ME ',', <select into clause> or FROM expected, got 'THEN'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am a mySQL user having to piece together an Oracle query and not doing well ...

I am getting these errors:

```
Unable to resolve symbol 'sa'
unexpected 'value'
',', <select into clause> or FROM expected, got 'THEN'
```

This my the query

```
SELECT
      sa.STA_AUTO_KEY
     , sa.CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
     , sa.INVC_NUMBER
     , sod.ROUTE_CODE
     , inh.INVOICE_DATE
     , sa.SHIP_DATE
     , inh.POST_DATE
     , inh.POST_STATUS
     , sa.TRAN_TYPE
     , sa.NEW_PN as PN
     , stm.DESCRIPTION
     , sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER as SERIAL_NUMBER
     , sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE as UNIT_PRICE
     , STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST
     , sa.NEW_UNIT_COST as UNIT_COST
     , sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH as QTY_INVOICED
     , sa.AMOUNT as GROSS
     , (stm.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST) as COST
     , sod.SOD_AUTO_KEY
     , sa.NEW_CONDITION_CODE as CONDITION_CODE
     , sys.USER_NAME as SALESPERSON_CODE
     , sa.SO_NUMBER
     , cmp.COMPANY_NAME
     , cmp.COMPANY_CODE
     , cnc.CONSIGNMENT_CODE
     , IF sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NULL THEN
            sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH) as GROSS
            sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH) - (STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST) as NET
        ELSEIF sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER = 'nsn' THEN
            sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH) as GROSS
            sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH) - (STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST) as NET
        ELSEIF sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER = 'NSN' THEN
            sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH) as GROSS
            sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH) - (STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST) as NET
        ELSE
         sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE as GROSS
         sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE - (STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST) as NET
        ENDIF
FROM STOCK_AUDIT sa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INVC_HEADER inh ON sa.INH_AUTO_KEY = inh.INH_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_DETAIL sod ON (sa.SOH_AUTO_KEY = sod.SOH_AUTO_KEY) AND (sa.SOD_AUTO_KEY = sod.SOD_AUTO_KEY)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK stm ON sa.NEW_STM_AUTO_KEY = stm.STM_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_USERS sys ON sod.SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = sys.SYSUR_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANIES cmp ON inh.CMP_AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CONSIGNMENT_CODES cnc ON sa.NEW_CNC_AUTO_KEY = cnc.CNC_AUTO_KEY
WHERE inh.POST_DATE >= TO_DATE ('2020-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND inh.POST_DATE <= TO_DATE ('2020-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND (sa.TRAN_TYPE = 'Post Invoice' OR sa.TRAN_TYPE = 'Invoice Return')
    AND sod.ROUTE_CODE IN ('M', 'S')
```

Any help is **GREATLY** appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF ... THEN ... ELSE` is not valid SQL syntax in Oracle (but you can use that syntax in PL/SQL).

You want to use `CASE` or `DECODE`. Like this:

```sql
SELECT
      sa.STA_AUTO_KEY
     , sa.CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
     , sa.INVC_NUMBER
     , sod.ROUTE_CODE
     , inh.INVOICE_DATE
     , sa.SHIP_DATE
     , inh.POST_DATE
     , inh.POST_STATUS
     , sa.TRAN_TYPE
     , sa.NEW_PN as PN
     , stm.DESCRIPTION
     , sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER as SERIAL_NUMBER
     , sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE as UNIT_PRICE
     , STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST
     , sa.NEW_UNIT_COST as UNIT_COST
     , sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH as QTY_INVOICED
     , sa.AMOUNT as GROSS
     , (stm.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST) as COST
     , sod.SOD_AUTO_KEY
     , sa.NEW_CONDITION_CODE as CONDITION_CODE
     , sys.USER_NAME as SALESPERSON_CODE
     , sa.SO_NUMBER
     , cmp.COMPANY_NAME
     , cmp.COMPANY_CODE
     , cnc.CONSIGNMENT_CODE
     , CASE
       WHEN sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NULL OR sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER IN ( 'nsn', 'NSN' )
       THEN sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH)
       ELSE sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE
       END AS gross
     , CASE
       WHEN sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NULL OR sa.NEW_SERIAL_NUMBER IN ( 'nsn', 'NSN' )
       THEN sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE * (sa.OLD_QTY_OH - sa.NEW_QTY_OH) - (STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST)
       ELSE sa.NEW_UNIT_PRICE - (STM.UNIT_FREIGHT_COST + sa.NEW_UNIT_COST)
       END AS net
FROM STOCK_AUDIT sa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INVC_HEADER inh ON sa.INH_AUTO_KEY = inh.INH_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_DETAIL sod ON (sa.SOH_AUTO_KEY = sod.SOH_AUTO_KEY) AND (sa.SOD_AUTO_KEY = sod.SOD_AUTO_KEY)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK stm ON sa.NEW_STM_AUTO_KEY = stm.STM_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_USERS sys ON sod.SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = sys.SYSUR_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANIES cmp ON inh.CMP_AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CONSIGNMENT_CODES cnc ON sa.NEW_CNC_AUTO_KEY = cnc.CNC_AUTO_KEY
WHERE   inh.POST_DATE >= DATE '2020-09-01'
    AND inh.POST_DATE <  DATE '2020-10-01'
    AND sa.TRAN_TYPE IN ( 'Post Invoice', 'Invoice Return' )
    AND sod.ROUTE_CODE IN ('M', 'S')
```

Don't use `2020-09-30` as the upper bound if your dates have a non-midnight time component as you will not get any data between `2020-09-30 00:00:01` and `2020-09-30 23:59:59`. Instead filter on `< DATE '2020-10-01'`.

Comment: You are a life-saver ... THANKS!

Comment: Side observation - you have one table (USER_NAME) in the SYS schema.  Bad, bad, bad. You should _never_ use the SYS schema for application data.

Comment: I will find another table that identifies the salesperson ... THANKS!

Comment: @EdStevens Unless all the OP's tables are in the `SYS` schema (which would be bad) then they are not using any tables from the `SYS` schema. They happen to have one called `SYS_USERS` but that has an underscore and not a dot in the name so it will be in the same schema as all the other tables.

Comment: @MT0 - copying and pasting from the the OP ---  ', sys.USER_NAME as SALESPERSON_CODE'.  sure looks like a dot after 'sys'.  And just in case my eyes or monitor are bad, I pasted it into notepdad and did a search for '.' (dot), and got a hit exactly where I expected.

Comment: @EdStevens The table name in the `FROM` clause is `SYS_USERS` and the OP has given it the alias `sys` so that when they are using `sys.USER_NAME` in the `SELECT` clause they are referring to `USER_NAME` column of the alias `sys` which is the `SYS_USERS` table in the current schema and not to a table in the `SYS` schema. Look further down and you will see `LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_USERS sys`.

Comment: @MT0 - ah, I missed the aliasing.  Lesson to me, (relearned): never underestimate the ability of a developer to obfuscate reality.